# Mdx Sum measure of dimension by Date

Tags: mdx, degenerate-dimension

I'm introducing into mdx language and I came up with a problem. I want to sum up length of streets (`DimStreet`) from dimension as calculated member in cube with hierarchy date to day level (e.g: `[DimDate].[Alldate].[Day]`) I done in SQL to give a better understanding:

```
SELECT f.date_utc_key, SUM(s.length)
    FROM "Fact_coord" as f
    INNER JOIN "DimStreet" as s
    GROUP BY date_utc_key
    ORDER BY date_utc_key asc
```

Comment: Please can you add your attempt in `mdx` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a `length` measure. If so, the below should work.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.SumOfLengths AS
SUM
(
   [DimDate].[Alldate].[Day].members, 
   [Measures].[Length]
)


SELECT Measures.SumOfLengths ON 0,
[DimDate].[Alldate].[Day].members ON 1
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: hi sourav - why are you including `EXISTING`? If you already have `[DimDate].[Alldate].[Day].members` on rows then you can just chuck `[Measures].[Length]` on columns and only the existing results will be shown on each row - this is SSAS's built-in autoexist behaviour

Comment: hi @Sourav_Agasti - it is possible accomplish the  `[Measure].[Length]` if is referenced on dimension and dynamical calculated  (like add dynamically on column to fact table)?